# Checking if control exists throws an error

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Really what I am after is a way to check if the control exists without throwing an error.

The code should look something like this:

```
Control myControl = UIMap.MyMainWindow; 

if (!myControl.Exists)
{
   //Do something here
}
```

The problem is that the control throws an error because it is invalid if it doesn't exist, essentially making the exists property useless.

What is the solution?

Comment: Try this: if (myControl.FindMatchingControls().Count == 0) { //DoSemthingHere }

Answer (score 3):

In this case I am using the tryfind method.

Like this:

```
            HtmlDiv list = new HtmlDiv(Window.GetWebtop());
            list.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
            list.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.InnerText, "Processing search", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
            if (list.TryFind())
            {
                //DO Something
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am re-posting the comment kida gave as a answer, because I think its the best solution.

```
Control myControl = UIMap.MyMainWindow; 

if (!myControl.FindMatchingControls().Count == 0)
{
   //Do something here
}
```

The **FindMatchingControls().Count** is much faster then the `Try Catch` or the `TryFind`. Since it does not wait for SearchTimeoutto check if the element is now there. Default it waits 30 seconds for the element to not be there, but I like my tests to fail fast.

Alternatively its possible to lower the `Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout` before the Catch or TryFind and restore it afterwards, but this is unnecessary code if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of two things:  Wrap your code in a try-catch block so the exception will be swallowed:

```
try
{
    if (!myControl.Exists)
    {
        // Do something here.
    }
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
}
```

Or, you could add more conditions:

```
if (!myControl.Exists)
{
    // Do something here.
}
else if (myControlExists)
{
    // Do something else.
}
else
{
    // If the others don't qualify 
    // (for example, if the object is null), this will be executed.
}
```

Personally, I like the catch block, because if I expect the control to be there as part of my test, I can `Assert.Fail(ex.ToString());` to stop the test right there and log the error message for use in bug reporting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that control will exist or enabled after some time you can use WaitForControlExist() or WaitForControlEnabled() methods with a default timeout or specified timeout.
I have a situation like this and I am looping until the control is available :

```
bool isSaveButtonExist = uISaveButton.WaitForControlEnabled();

            while (!isSaveButtonExist )
            {
                try
                {
                    uISaveButton.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
                    uISaveButton.SetFocus(); // setting focus for the save button if found
                    isSaveButtonExist = uISaveButton.WaitForControlExist(100);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // exception for every set focus message if the control not exist
                }

            }
            // do something with found save button
            // Click 'Save' button
            Mouse.Click(uISaveButton, new Point(31, 37));
```

please refer to this link for more about these Methods:

[Make playback wait methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamg/archive/2010/02/12/how-to-make-playback-wait-for-certain-event.aspx)